# Full width Carousel with Dynamic Background

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, slideshow, carousel

I need a slider or carousel that has an outer div with a background color that will change with each slide.  The outer div will not resize, but the inner div containing the carousel images will scale down with screen sizes once it is below 960px.

Not looking for a full screen carousel, only a full width.

Thanks!

SC

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show your in-progress code?

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I have tried a whole bunch of stuff, but it has been mainly hacking plugins to try to get them to work.  What i need is a cross between the slider found here: http://playastory.com/ and the slider found here: http://simplymusicpiano.com/ the background div with the changing color needs to collapse while the slide doesn't start to respond until under 960px.  hope this makes sense.  Thanks again!

Comment: I ended up constructing 3 different sliders and using media queries to show only one at each screen width.  Maybe not the best practice for front end development, but it solved this problem I've been working on for a couple of weeks.